# Anerkannte Klassifikation von Possessivpronomina im Deutschen

Tags: pronoun, terminology, possessive-pronoun

Ich unterrichte wieder einmal Deutsch und die Kleinen haben viele Schwierigkeiten mit den Pronomina. Ich lehre gern natürlich und ohne zu viel Grammatik, welche nicht meine Stärke ist, aber ich glaube ihnen eine Systematik geben zu müssen.

Nun spreche ich selbst viele Sprachen und systematisiere die Possessivpronomina etwas komplexer. Offensichtlich gibt es mindestens folgende Fälle, die ich nach meiner eigenen Art benannt habe:

- Pronomen ersetzt Substantiv, substantivisches Pronomen: *Das ist **meiner**.*
- Wie Prädikativadjektiv, Adjektivpronomen: *Dieser Hut ist **mein**.*
- Ersetzt Artikel, Pronominalartikel: *Dies ist **mein** Hut!*

Ich möchte wissen welche Unterscheidungen in der Deutschen Grammatik anerkannt sind, denn ich möchte nichts lehren, das in irgendwelchen Prüfungen durchgestrichen würde. Ich habe diverse Seiten gefunden, aber sie sprachen meist von mehreren Sprachen, so dass ich nicht wusste wie linguistisch oder experimentell sie waren.

Insbesondere beim zweiten Fall frage ich mich, ob man überhaupt offiziell von einem Pronomen spricht, oder nicht besser von einem Adverbialadjektiv. Und wäre nicht auch folgendes ein (attributives) Adjektiv?

> *Ist ihr Mann schon zurück? **Der meine** ging angeln!*

Edit

---

Mittlerweile (vielleicht immer schon) findet sich in [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronomen) folgendes:

> Manche Pronomina werden wie ein Substantiv verwendet (Substantivpronomen, substantivisches Pronomen; Beispiel: das Auto ist meines), andere begleiten ein Substantiv ähnlich wie sonst ein Adjektiv (Adjektivpronomen, adjektivisches Pronomen; Beispiel: mein Auto).

In einem späteren Abschnitt steht außerdem - und das erklärt die Antwort von idmean:

> In der modernen Linguistik werden die Begriffe Nomen und Substantiv gleichgesetzt und der Begriff Pronomen im Sinne von substantivisches Pronomen eingeschränkt

Comment: Ggf auch eine Frage für [linguistics.se].

Comment: @Jan von mir aus können wir sie gerne verschieben!

Comment: Nicht zu verschieben. Es geht speziell um deutsche Grammatiken, bzw. was man als 'Schulgrammatik' bezeichnen könnte. Das ist hier schon richtig.

Comment: 5 Sekunden googeln gefolgt von 3 Minuten querlesen ergaben diese drei recht brauchbaren Seiten: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/pronomen/possessivpronomen - https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessiv_(Linguistik) - http://mein-deutschbuch.de/possessivpronomen.html

Comment: @HubertSchölnast stimmt. Die habe ich alle besucht. Ich würde sagen die erste und letzte liefern keine Klassifikation mit Namen. Die Wikipediaseite wohl, aber da weiß ich nicht, ob sie kanonisch ist für das Deutsche, oder eher die Idee irgendeines Linguisten. Dann ist da noch diese Seite, die sehr ähnlich argumentiert wie ich: http://thumulla.com/home/possessivpronomen_possessivartikel_oder_possessivadjektiv_.html Auch hier vermute ich eigene Wortschöpfungen.

Comment: Was soll ein Adverbialadjektiv sein? Substantivisches Pronomen ist Unsinn. Das ist der ganz normale Gebrauch von Pronomen (Der eine blieb, der andere ging), dass sie attributiv verwendet werden können, ist auch ganz gewöhnlich (der eine Mann kam zuerst, dann der andere Mann).

Comment: @deponensvogel http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_typ=o&v_id=3996

Comment: Ach so, ich bin kurz auf dem Schlauch gestanden. Hab die ganze Zeit ›Adjektivadverb‹ gedacht.

Comment: So, was ich jetzt noch hinzufügen wollte. Beim Satz ›Dieser Hut ist mein‹ ist das ein eher ungewöhnlicher Fall. Aber adverbial ist daran gar nichts. Ich würde es einfach als Pronomen führen. Auch dein letztes Beispiel sieht sehr nach einem normalen Pronomen aus, da der Bedeutungsgehalt (wie bei Pronomen üblich) nur aus dem Kontext erkennbar ist.

Comment: Klar sind das alles Pronomina. Darum geht es ja auch. Ich habe jetzt gefragt wie diese anerkanntermaßen klassifiziert werden und auf der Basis anderer Sprachen (vielleicht stupide) versucht zu demonstrieren was es alles für Fälle gibt!

Comment: Ich sehe eigentlich keinen Unterschied zwischen das erste und zweite Beispiel. Und die Formulierung "Der meine ging angeln!" verwendet keiner. Höchstens: Meiner ging angeln.

Comment: Ich denke "Der Meine" in diesem Beispiel ist nur ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, kein Possessivpronomen. Verwendet wird das, in verschiedenen Ausprägungen, definitiv.

Answer (score 2):

> Dieser Hut ist mein.

*mein* ist der veraltete Genitiv von *ich*, also ein Personalpronomen.<sup>1</sup> Der Satz ist also die Antwort auf „Wessen Hut ist das?“.

Es liegt hier keine besondere Nutzung dieses Pronomens vor: Personalpronomen ersetzen immer ein Substantiv, die nähere Bestimmung ist eigentlich unnötig. 
Ich weiß ehrlich gesagt auch nicht, was *Prädikativadjektiv* bedeuten soll. Ich sehe keinen Zusammenhang mit dem Prädikat.

> Das ist meiner.

*meiner* ist der gegenwärtig gebräuchliche Genitiv von *ich*.<sup>2</sup> Selbiges gilt.

> Dies ist mein Hut!

*mein* ist ein attributiv gebrauchtes Possessivpronomen. Eigentlich auch das übliche.

> Der meine ging angeln!

Hier wird das Possessivpronomen nicht attributiv aber mit Artikel gebraucht und dekliniert daher anders. Es ist aber trotzdem ein Possessivpronomen.<sup>3</sup> [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein) hat schöne Tabellen über die Konjunktion dieses Possessivpronomens.

Wie schon in den Kommentaren angemerkt, sind Sätze wie der erste und der vierte sowieso eher sehr selten. Eine genaue grammatikalische Beschreibung würde ich hier gar nicht erst versuchen – und lernt man auch nicht in der Schule, vielleicht wenn man Germanistik studiert.

---

<sup>1</sup> http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mein_ich
<sup>2</sup> http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meiner
<sup>3</sup> http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mein_Possessivpronomen

Comment: Hier zum prädikativen Adjektiv: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/praedikativ-adverbial-attributiv

Comment: Sogar für mich als Muttersprachler erstaunlich, daß in „der Hut ist mein“ und „der Hut ist grün“ die Wörter „mein“ und „grün“ so unterschiedlich sind...

Comment: Hier zum substantivischen und adjektivischen Pronomen: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronomen